Sensored BLDC Commutation Controller code
For context, I'm using a maxII epm240 cpld, and I want to be able to program this to FPGAs too. I know I could build this in a typical state machine fashion since a sensored BLDC motor controller is a Mealy state machine. But, I figured that since I can use the motor as the clock to facilitate state updating, all I needed was a combinational logic to decide how the Commutation Controller works.
This combinatorial logic works, and I have built a motor controller out of it. I was just wondering whether this type of way of building a Mealy state machine is problematic or if there's any way I could improve this code.
Here is the link to my github to see more details:
https://github.com/SimNabong/Sensored-Brushless-DC-Motor-Controller/tree/main
module CommutationControl(
    input clk,
    input [2:0]UI, 
    input [2:0]HS, //Hall Sensors 
    output [5:0]PT //6 Power Transistor control signals
);
    /*
      UI[0](Regen Break One) or UI[1]&UI[2](Regen Break Two)
      UI[1] is clockwise spin
      UI[2] is counter-cw spin
      HS[0],HS[1],HS[2] are the HS sensor signals
    */  
    
    wire Aw,Bw,Cw,Dw,Ew,Fw;
    reg [1:0]Ar = 2'd0;
    reg [1:0]Br = 2'd0;
    reg [1:0]Cr = 2'd0;
    reg [1:0]Dr = 2'd0;
    reg [1:0]Er = 2'd0;
    reg [1:0]Fr = 2'd0; //registers for delays


    assign Aw = ~HS[0]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[2] | ~HS[1]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1] | ~HS[0]&HS[1]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[1]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | HS[1]&~HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2];
    
    assign Bw = HS[1]&~HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | ~HS[1]&HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[2]&~UI[0]&~UI[1]&UI[2] | ~HS[0]&HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | ~HS[0]&HS[1]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | HS[1]&~HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&~UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[1]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2];
    
    assign Cw = HS[0]&~HS[1]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | ~HS[1]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | ~HS[0]&HS[1]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | HS[1]&~HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1] | ~HS[0]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2];
    
    assign Dw = ~HS[0]&HS[1]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[1]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | ~HS[0]&HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | ~HS[1]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&~UI[1]&UI[2] | ~HS[1]&HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | HS[1]&~HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | ~HS[0]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&~UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2];
    
    assign Ew = ~HS[0]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[1]&~UI[0]&UI[2] | ~HS[1]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | HS[1]&~HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | ~HS[0]&HS[1]&~UI[0]&UI[1];
    
    assign Fw = HS[0]&~HS[1]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&~UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[1]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | ~HS[0]&HS[1]&~UI[0]&~UI[1]&UI[2] | HS[0]&~HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | ~HS[0]&HS[1]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | ~HS[1]&HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | ~HS[0]&HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2] | HS[1]&~HS[2]&UI[0]&~UI[1]&~UI[2];
    
    
    always@(posedge clk)begin  //introduces a dead-time that prevents power transistors in the same bridge from being on at the same time, because if they did then that would cause a short in  the battery. This part however can be removed if the gate drivers has this capability. This dead-time needs to be adjusted based on the turn off/on delay of the power trans used.
    
        Ar[0] <= Aw&~Br[1];
        Ar[1] <= Ar[0]; 
        Br[0] <= Bw&~Ar[1]; 
        Br[1] <= Br[0];
        
        
        Cr[0] <= Cw&~Dr[1];
        Cr[1] <= Cr[0];
        Dr[0] <= Dw&~Cr[1];
        Dr[1] <= Dr[0];
        
        Er[0] <= Ew&~Fr[1];
        Er[1] <= Er[0];
        Fr[0] <= Fw&~Er[1];
        Fr[1] <= Fr[0];     
        
    end
    

    assign PT = {Ar[1],Br[1],Cr[1],Dr[1],Er[1],Fr[1]};



endmodule


Is your code working correctly or not ?

@BillalBegueradj yeah it works correctly. I posted the simulation waveform in my github along with the truth table I used. I also have the older version of this code without the regenerative braking function that I documented in video.  I built it using discrete logic gate ICs so it's kinda silly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUQjvkLtdNA

@MisterMoron: If you would also like the testbench code which is in your github link to be reviewed, I recommend posting the code in a new question.

@toolic I just looked at my tb code and got depressed by the horrendous spacing lol. I'm over it now and will be posting what I think is a better version of it soon.

@MisterMoron: Don't be too hard on yourself.  It is hard to write efficient code when you are just starting with a new language.  I posted an answer to your new question.

Overview
It is good that you did the following:

Chose a meaningful name for the module
Used ANSI-style module ports instead of the older style
Declared one port per line for better readability
Added comments
Used proper and consistent indentation
Used nonblocking assignments in the sequential logic always block

Here are some suggestions for improvement.
Long lines
The assign statements are much too long for a single line.
Even with the large screen I am using, I need to scroll horizontally too much.
This impedes understanding of the design.  You can easily break up each
single line into many lines.  For example:
assign Aw = ~HS[0]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[2] | 
            ~HS[1]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[1] | 
            ~HS[0]&HS[1]&~UI[0]&UI[1]&UI[2] | // etc.

The same is true for the comment after the always block.
You should break that up into several lines inside a "block" comment.
For example:
/*
    Introduces a dead-time that prevents power transistors in the same bridge
    from being on at the same time, because if they did,
    then that would cause a short in the battery.
    etc.
*/
always@(posedge clk)begin  

Vertical whitespace
The code would be easier to understand if there were more of it to read
on the screen at once.  You should collapse all multiple blank lines
into a single blank line:
    always@(posedge clk)begin    
        Ar[0] <= Aw&~Br[1];
        Ar[1] <= Ar[0]; 
        Br[0] <= Bw&~Ar[1]; 
        Br[1] <= Br[0];
        
        Cr[0] <= Cw&~Dr[1];
        Cr[1] <= Cr[0];
        Dr[0] <= Dw&~Cr[1];
        Dr[1] <= Dr[0];
        
        Er[0] <= Ew&~Fr[1];
        Er[1] <= Er[0];
        Fr[0] <= Fw&~Er[1];
        Fr[1] <= Fr[0];     
    end
    
    assign PT = {Ar[1],Br[1],Cr[1],Dr[1],Er[1],Fr[1]};
endmodule

Horizontal whitespace
Code is easier to read with space around some operators.
For example:
    Ar[0] <= Aw & ~Br[1];

It is good to have space around signal ranges:
input [2:0] UI, 

It is good to use space after commas:
assign PT = {Ar[1], Br[1], Cr[1], Dr[1], Er[1], Fr[1]};

Also use space around keywords:
always @(posedge clk) begin

Naming
Use meaningful names for the signals.  For example, instead of
an abbreviation like HS, use words like hall_sensors.
With a descriptive name like this, the comments become redundant
and can be removed.  Using proper naming makes the code more
self-documenting.
It is more customary to use all lower-case letter for signal names.
All caps is typically used for constant values, like a parameter.
PT can be power_transistors.
I have no idea what UI means.  There is a good chance that you will
even forget what it means a year from now when you look back at your code.
You could consider spitting this input into 3 separate signals with
meaningful names.  For example, UI[2] could be ccw_spin.
Naming the wires and regs A-F is not very meaningful.  If the letters
do have some meaning, you should at least add comments describing
what they stand for.
Reset
It is common for digital logic to use a dedicated input signal to reset
the design.  Perhaps this is not required for your FPGA, but it is
worth considering to make the code more portable.  For example,
initializing registers this way may not be synthesizable with
other design flows:
reg [1:0]Ar = 2'd0;

State machine
I would not classify the module as any type of state machine.
In Verilog, a state machine is typically coded with a state
register, parameter constants for each state, and a case
statement to describe transitions between the states.  Here is an example of an FSM.
Perhaps your Mealy FSM is implemented in another module.
Abstraction
Seeing all those sum-of-products (like ~HS[0]&HS[2]&~UI[0]&UI[2]) makes me wonder if you are coding at too low a level of abstraction.  It is not evident to me how code this at a higher level because I don't understand the design, but it is something for you to consider.

ty for recommending me this board! The long lines is due to my editor having word wrap. I'll keep the naming convention, the white space rules, and initialization of regs in mind for the next version of this code. "UI" means "user inputs" forgot the comment, sorry. I used abbreviations so I don't clutter-up the Boolean expressions, but if naming conventions outweighs that then I'll go for a proper name next time. I should've been clearer about this module only becoming a state machine only when the motor is connected.  The 3 HS of the motor gives 6 different states, UI and the state di

ctates which (PT)power transistors are activated which then causes the motor to behave a certain way or change the position of its rotor. So the motor gives the states of the machine with the hall sensors. The motor is also responsible for the updating of the states. The hall sensors gives 6 different states in binary 001, 011,010,110,101. I then combined it with the UI to dictate which of the power transistors are turned on, which then in turn cause the motor to behave a certain way, like change it's rotor position which also changes the hall sensor signal or change the state of the machine.

It's not a typical state machine, since it doesn't use a clock to update or change its state that's the motors responsibility. It also doesn't need a parameter for its states since the motor provides the states through its hall sensors. I hope that clarifies things.

@MisterMoron:  All of the information in your comments here would be useful as comments in your Verilog code.
